# When I try to run project on device or emulator, only the action bar with app title shows up. Nothing else

Tags: android

I've been attempting to run my project on my phone and my emulator, and in both locations all I see is the action bar with the name of my app. Everything else is blank.

There are no errors in either the emulator logcat or the device logcat. Anyone know what's going on?

Here is the warning filter applied to the emulator logcat:

```
-"06-23 15:20:38.409  2383-2395/com.example.android.appname W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.019ms
-06-23 15:20:38.832 2383-2480/com.example.android.appname W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
-06-23 15:20:38.832    2383-2480/com.example.android.appname W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43d5900, error=EGL_SUCCESS
-06-23 15:20:39.190    2383-2390/com.example.android.appname W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 35.214ms"
```

Java Code for launcher activity:

```
package com.example.android.apptitle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;


public class Apptitle extends ActionBarActivity {
    private TextView mTextDetails;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    Button b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
     /*   FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
        AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                    AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                    AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                // App code
            }
        }; */
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_app_title, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void introView (View view)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, HomePage2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling [`setContentView(R.layout.your_xml)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)) in your `onCreate` anywhere. Call that before trying to access your button.

Comment: That's embarrassing for me, but that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about setContentView method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); //add this line
```